# Getting unexpected position value from binarySearch method in java

Tags: java

Currently working with java basics.While learning I've written the following code.

```
import java.util.*;
class RemoveDuplicates{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = {1,2,3,1,5,2,3};
        int[] out = {1,2,3,1,5,2,3};
        for(int each : arr){
            System.out.println("Element "+each+" at "+Arrays.binarySearch(out,each));
        }
    }
}
```

**My expected output:**

Element 1 at 3

Element 2 at 5

Element 3 at 6

Element 1 at 3

Element 5 at 4

Element 2 at 5

Element 3 at 6

**My actual output:**

Element 1 at 3

Element 2 at 5

Element 3 at 6

Element 1 at 3

Element 5 at -8

Element 2 at 5

Element 3 at 6

In my actual output at element 5 why I'm getting -8 from `Arrays.binarySeach(out,each)` function?

Explain me this please.

Comment: You know that you must provide a sorted array for `Arrays.binarySearch()`, don't you?

Comment: Oh god.I totally forgot it.Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always remember for binary search to work you must sort the array.
Use can use `Arrays.sort()` for sorting

```java
import java.util.*;
class RemoveDuplicates{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 1, 5, 2, 3};
        int[] out = {1, 2, 3, 1, 5, 2, 3};
        Arrays.sort(out);
        for(int each : arr) {
            System.out.println("Element "+each+" at "+Arrays.binarySearch(out,each));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If u want to use binary search, u should sort the array first.
add
`Arrays.sort(out);`

Besides, FYI, there is no guarantee for multiple elements.

here's some infs for `Arrays.binarySearch(int[], int)`

Searches the specified array of ints for the specified value using the binary search algorithm. **The array must be sorted** (as by the sort(int[]) method) prior to making this call. If it is not sorted, the results are undefined. **If the array contains multiple elements** with the specified value, **there is no guarantee which one will be found.**